# Delete and arrow keys not working

Tags: 12.04, gnome

After installing 12.04 and Gnome Shell, I find that the arrow and delete keys, along with the insert, home, page up & down, and end keys have stopped working.

All these keys now appear to be XF86MonBrightnessdown whatever that is.

Any fix for this?

Comment: Have you run `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-layout` to see if that resolves the issue?

Comment: alistair@Main:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-layout
[sudo] password for alistair: 
Package `keyboard-layout' is not installed and no info is available.
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: keyboard-layout is not installed.
alistair@Main:~$ sudo apt-get install keyboard-layout
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package keyboard-layout

Comment: Whoops. Sorry, I was in a bit of a rush when I typed this up. I meant `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`.