# Up, down, right arrow keys and delete key not working

Tags: 12.04, keyboard

I have already read [Delete and arrow keys not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305808/delete-and-arrow-keys-not-working) and tried what is written there. I have also tried restarting my computer. I have also searched elsewhere for answers, but I haven't found any solution.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, and there were not problems yesterday, but for the last hour, I've had the following problem.

When I press the up or the right arrow, nothing happens. When I press the down arrow, it doesn't make anything go down, but something appears in the upper right corner of my screen:

[image: picture1]

When I press the delete key, nothing gets deleted, but something appears in the upper right corner of my screen:

[image: picture2]

The left arrow still works. Can anybody help me get my three arrow keys and delete key back?

Comment: Having the exact same problem. Are you able to solve it?